# Differences in JPA auto increment

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa, orm

When I want to set my PK auto increment(MySQL), I can do it by table settings in database, or by anotation

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

My question is, what is difference and why use which access. Is one of them better? Thanx for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have thought that the docs for any JPA implementation would explain all of that
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Ids/GeneratedValue

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jpa/value_generation.html